# calling static blocks from static blocks

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

i have a problem with my new top menu of my magento..
i've made new link in top menu, in `top.phtml` i add this script..

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('faq')->toHtml() ?>
```

then in cms i make new block..

```
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}"><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
```

my problem is, i want to call another static blocks, ex. title=test1 n identifier=test2. what must i write inside url="" in cms? or any solution? really need your help guys..

im in magento 1.4.1.1..

Answer (score 3):

you can call blocks in cms pages like this:

`{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block id"}}`